# Pipe data from curl_easy_perform

Tags: c, curl, pipe, libcurl

I am trying to use libcurl to pipe data from an arbitrary (user given) url to my application:

- The [https.c](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/https.html) example shows how to retrieve content from a URL and immediately write it to somewhere as it comes in, for example stdout or a file.
- The [sendrecv.c](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/sendrecv.html) example shows how to setup a pipe by making the application repeatedly call `curl_easy_recv` to retrieve chunks of data.

However I don't understand how to combine the two. It seems like `curl_easy_recv` only works when:

```
/* Do not do the transfer - only connect to host */ 
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_CONNECT_ONLY, 1L);
```

When this option is set `curl_easy_perform` does not retrieve any data, it just connects. In the example, the application proceeds by manually sending an http command using `curl_easy_send`. However I just want to retrieve the data specified in the URL, without writing manual http or ftp commands.

Is there a way to use `curl_easy_recv` or something similar in combination with the default behavior of `curl_easy_perform` automatically taking care of retrieving the content specified in the url?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, [curl_easy_send](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/curl_easy_send.html) and [curl_easy_recv](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/curl_easy_recv.html) are really only meant to be used if you're not doing one of the protocols libcurl already supports so in most cases they are not the correct answer. It doesn't sound like you need them.

[curl_easy_perform](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/curl_easy_perform.html)() does the transfer of the given URL and it'll call the [CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION.html) as soon as data has arrived and you can then make use of that data or send it somewhere of your choice. Is that not enough?

Comment: Thank you, I now understand I need to use the multi interface instead of `curl_easy_recv` for a streaming client.